# How to be prepared for a pop quiz

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

At the last minute of the last class of the week, the logic teacher said to the class

> Next week, if I can, I will hold a surprise quiz in one of our lessons.
>
> The quiz will be about everything we've learned throughout the year, including homework. I'm going to make the hardest quiz I possibly can.
>
> Those who will fail, will have to come to reinforcement lessons over the weekend.

Then the teacher exited the classroom, leaving everyone in slight shock. Some students went to Charlie, a very good student usually, who seemed surprisingly calm. When they came close, Charlie said

> Don't worry, no one will have to study in the weekend.

**How did Charlie know this?**

Clarifications:

- Charlie didn't have any prior knowledge on the quiz, or on the teacher's whereabouts the following week.
- This is the middle of the semester. There's a lot of material
- There are 3 classes of logic a week

Answer (score 3):

The teacher said

> he will hold a surprise quiz **if he can**. But Charlie already knows about the "accident" the teacher will have this weekend.

Comment: That's dark man

Answer (score 0):

Well

> The teacher said he would hold a **surprise** quiz **if he can**. But since he already told everyone about it, it's no longer a surprise, so he can't have a surprise quiz.

Comment: But they dont know when it will be, that's the surprise

Comment: @Dotan I mean, in my experience if the quiz is announced, it's not a surprise, even if the teacher doesn't specify a date

Comment: For the sake of the question, not knowing the day counts as a surprise